# jQuery animation, coming in from one side, passing and object and out the other. Straight lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm in week one of learning javaScript and jQuery and I'm trying to do some animation.

Basically all I want to do is have these arrows start off screen, come in from one side, pass threw the target, and exit the opposite side of the screen.

Ideally it would be one fires and when it's roughly 3/4 of the way across the screen the next fires for all 8 arrows.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jQuery.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="jQuery.js" type"text/javaScript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="clickme">
        Click Me
    </button>
    <span class="uparrow">
    </span>
    <span class="uparrow2">
    </span>
    <span class="downarrow">
    </span>
    <span class="downarrow2">
    </span>
    <span class="leftarrow">
    </span>
    <span class="leftarrow2">
    </span>
    <span class="rightarrow">
    </span>
    <span class="rightarrow2">
    </span>
    <div class="target">
        <img src="http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/target1.svg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="target2">
        <img src="http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/target1.svg" alt="">
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

CSS    -----------All of the arrows are currently placed on the targets location and hidden.

```
.uparrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    top: 23%;
    left: 23%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.uparrow2 {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    top: 63%;
    left: 63%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.downarrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid red;
    top: 23%;
    left: 23%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.downarrow2 {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid red;
    top: 63%;
    left: 63%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.left arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid red;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    top: 65%;
    left: 63%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.leftarrow2 {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid red;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    top: 25%;
    left: 23%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.rightarrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 100px solid red;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    top: 25%;
    left: 23%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.rightarrow2 {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 100px solid red;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    top: 65%;
    left: 63%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.target {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 60%;
}
.target2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

jQuery   ---- I've tried a few things but I'm at a loss basically want it to fire when the button is clicked.  I'm confused if it's my CSS position initially or if it's something else.

```
$(document).ready( function(){

$(".clickme").click( function() {

//end click function    
});
//end document
});
```

How would I go about doing this, just straight lines, passing threw the targets.

Comment: Can you start a jsfiddle.net to illustrate?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type"text/javaScript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.uparrow { width: 0; height: 0; border-left: 50px solid transparent; border-right: 50px solid transparent; border-bottom: 100px solid red; top: 23%; left: 23%; position: absolute; display: none; } .uparrow2 { width: 0; height: 0; border-left: 50px solid transparent; border-right: 50px solid transparent; border-bottom: 100px solid red; top: 63%; left: 63%; position: absolute; display: none; } .downarrow { width: 0; height: 0; border-left: 50px solid transparent; border-right: 50px solid transparent; border-top: 100px solid red; top: 23%; left: 23%; position: absolute; display: none; } .downarrow2 { width: 0; height: 0; border-left: 50px solid transparent; border-right: 50px solid transparent; border-top: 100px solid red; top: 63%; left: 63%; position: absolute; display: none; } .left arrow { width: 0; height: 0; border-top: 50px solid transparent; border-right: 100px solid red; border-bottom: 50px solid transparent; top: 65%; left: 63%; position: absolute; display: none; } .leftarrow2 { width: 0; height: 0; border-top: 50px solid transparent; border-right: 100px solid red; border-bottom: 50px solid transparent; top: 25%; left: 23%; position: absolute; display: none; } .rightarrow { width: 0; height: 0; border-top: 50px solid transparent; border-left: 100px solid red; border-bottom: 50px solid transparent; top: 25%; left: 23%; position: absolute; display: none; } .rightarrow2 { width: 0; height: 0; border-top: 50px solid transparent; border-left: 100px solid red; border-bottom: 50px solid transparent; top: 65%; left: 63%; position: absolute; display: none; } .target { width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto; position: absolute; top: 60%; left: 60%; } .target2 { width: 200px; height: 200px; position: absolute; top: 20%; left: 20%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="clickme">
        Click Me
    </button>
    <span class="uparrow">
    </span>
    <span class="uparrow2">
    </span>
    <span class="downarrow">
    </span>
    <span class="downarrow2">
    </span>
    <span class="leftarrow">
    </span>
    <span class="leftarrow2">
    </span>
    <span class="rightarrow">
    </span>
    <span class="rightarrow2">
    </span>
    <div class="target">
        me
    </div>
    <div class="target2">
        me
    </div>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(document).ready( function(){

$(".clickme").click( function() {

//end click function    
});
//end document
});
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `animate`. I did the first target in the jsFiddle below--I think it's what you were thinking.

```
$(document).ready( function(){

$(".clickme").on( 'click', function() {

  $('.downarrow').show().animate({ bottom: -100 }, function() { 
    $(this).css({ display: 'none', bottom: "100%" });
  });

  $('.uparrow').show().animate({ top: -100 }, function() { 
    $(this).css({ display: 'none', top: "100%" });
  });

  $('.leftarrow').show().animate({ left: -100 }, function() { 
    $(this).css({ display: 'none', left: "100%" });
  });

  $('.rightarrow').show().animate({ right: -100 }, function() { 
    $(this).css({ display: 'none', right: "100%" });
  });

});
});
```

Here's the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7f0zmxzp/

I changed a few positions in your CSS.

The `animate` method moves your arrows across the screen, and the callback method with `css()` resets the arrows after the animation.